# KSQL all messages failing in stream and there is data in topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am relatively new to Kafka Stream and trying to print out a the messages in the stream I created.
Can someone tell me why all the messages are failed?

When I use the print command I get this

```
print 'main' from beginning limit 10;
Key format: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ - no data processed
Value format: KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 2021/05/29 14:17:57.375 Z, key: <null>, value: A-1,2,5/21/2019 8:29,5/21/2019 9:29,34.808868,-82.269157,34.808868,-82.269157,0,Accident on Tanner Rd at Pennbrooke Ln.,439,Tanner Rd,R,Greenville,Greenville,SC,29607-6027,US,U
S/Eastern,KGMU,5/21/2019 8:53,76,76,52,28.91,10,N,7,0,Fair,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,Day,Day,Day,Day
```

When I run describe extended of the stream I created I get the below:

```
Name                 : ACCIDENTS_ORIGINAL
Type                 : STREAM
Timestamp field      : START_TIME
Key format           : KAFKA 
Value format         : DELIMITED
Kafka topic          : main (partitions: 1, replication: 1)
Statement            : CREATE STREAM ACCIDENTS_ORIGINAL (ID STRING, SEVERITY INTEGER, START_TIME STRING, 
END_TIME STRING, START_LAT DOUBLE, START_LNG DOUBLE, END_LAT DOUBLE, END_LNG DOUBLE, DISTANCE DOUBLE, 
DESCRIPTION STRING, NUMBER DOUBLE, STREET STRING, SIDE STRING, CITY STRING, COUNTY STRING, 
STATE STRING, ZIPCODE STRING, COUNTRY STRING, TIMEZONE STRING, AIRPORT_CODE STRING, 
WEATHER_TIME STRING, TEMPERATURE DOUBLE, WIND_CHILL DOUBLE, HUMIDITY DOUBLE, 
PRESSURE DOUBLE, VISIBILITY DOUBLE, WIND_DIRECTION STRING, WIND_SPEED STRING, 
PRECIPITATION DOUBLE, WEATHER_CONDITION STRING, AMENITY BOOLEAN, BUMP BOOLEAN, 
CROSSING BOOLEAN, GIVE_WAY BOOLEAN, JUNCTION BOOLEAN, NO_EXIT BOOLEAN, RAILWAY BOOLEAN, 
ROUNDABOUT BOOLEAN, STATION BOOLEAN, STOP BOOLEAN, TRAFFIC_CALMING BOOLEAN, 
TRAFFIC_SIGNAL BOOLEAN, TURNING_LOOP BOOLEAN, SUNRISE_SUNSET STRING, 
CIVIL_TWILIGHT STRING, NAUTICAL_TWILIGHT STRING, ASTRONOMICAL_TWILIGHT STRING)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='main', KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA', TIMESTAMP='Start_Time', 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');
```

Can anyone help me have a look and tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Small update, I also tried to set Key format as none and still get all the messages failed.

Comment: Maybe it's not working because your timestamp format has year first, but your data doesn't

Comment: Thanks! I have changed the timestamp format and now it works.